# Error: Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Object' to 'Decimal'

Tags: vb.net

I am tying to check the value of cell J34 (excel). If that value is null then display message, if not run the rest of the code.

However, when I am compiling I get the error above on line:

decAnnualMid = Convert.ToDecimal(Globals.dsbPositionBoard.Range("J34").Value)

Here is the rest of my code

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Private Sub chk10thPercentile_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chk10thPercentile.CheckedChanged
    'This event runs when the 10th checkbox is checked
    'The event clears the cells where the value will be pasted
    'enters the value from cell J34 into calculationShet H45 and clears
    'the checkboxes for 25th, 50th, 75th, 90th and Other Amount
    'checkboxes.

    Dim decAnnualMid As Decimal
    If chk25thPercentile.Checked = True And Globals.dsbPositionBoard.Range("J34").Value Is DBNull.Value Then
        'Display is user has not selected a position in the dashboard.
        MsgBox("The Market Data section of the Position Dashboard does not have a value for the 10th Percentile.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Input Error")
        Me.Close()
    Else
        'convert the value of K34 to decimal and
        decAnnualMid = Convert.ToDecimal(Globals.dsbPositionBoard.Range("J34").Value)


        'convert annual salary to hourly
        decHourlyMid = decAnnualMid / 52 / 40

        'display in the Mid label box
        lblAnnualMid.Text = decAnnualMid.ToString("C")
        lblHourlyMid.Text = decHourlyMid.ToString("C")

        'Uncheck all other boxes

        chk25thPercentile.Checked = False
        chk50thPercentile.Checked = False
        chk75thPercentile.Checked = False
        chk90thPercentile.Checked = False
        chkOtherAmount.Checked = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Range("J34") produces an object reference of type Object, not Range.  You'll have to cast to keep Option Strict On happy:

```
Dim sel As Range = CType(Globals.dsbPositionBoard.Range("J34"), Range)
decAnnualMid = Convert.ToDecimal(sel.Value)
```